# How to hide a li element in a dataTable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to hide the black list item depending on the the checkbox (Hide completed) being selected or not and show only the red ones. If there are no red ones in a row, entire row should be hidden. If there are no list items in a row, the row should be hidden too.

Also depending on the count of items in the list, the table metric should be updated. For example, if I hide all the black items, the completed one should show 0 and missing will be 1.

How can I do this using jquery?

Here is a fiddle:
(https://jsfiddle.net/skb25/ezvps3hL)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var otable = $('#table_id').DataTable({
        "paging": true
    });
    $('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the column API object
        var column = otable.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible(!column.visible());
    });
    var hideParamNode = document.getElementById('hideParam');
    hideParamNode.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        hideParameterization(hideParamNode);
    })

    function hideParameterization(hideParamNode) {
        var pElems = document.getElementsByClassName('paramName');
        if (hideParamNode.checked) {
            Object.keys(pElems).forEach(function (key) {
                pElems[key].style.display = "none";
            })
        } else {
            Object.keys(pElems).forEach(function (key) {
                pElems[key].style.display = "";
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: so ... why do you have jQuery? Part of the initial point of using a library like jQuery, is to code less. You obviously have jQuery, but your barely using it and when you do it's mixed in vanilla making your code a pain to read. I don't really see any reason for a single line of vanilla in all that code. You could rewrite it all in half as many lines using jQuery syntax

Comment: I tried my hand at doing it without jquery but it is not elegant and does not seem to work well with the datatable code. Thats why i need help writing less lines of code. "function hideParameterization" is a supposed to be removed. Can you help?

Comment: I can, but not atm. I'm pressed for time. However, I'd strongly suggest you jump through a couple jQuery example sites and reproduce them. You obviously understand vanilla, and you'll find jQuery ***SUPER EASY***. Once you do that, I'm plenty sure you will hit the API site and find your answer within minutes. jQuery is very elegant, but also VERY easy. It's basically .Net for JavaScript.